# LazyInitializationException (sometimes) with "left join fetch" Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

a very strange `LazyInitializationException`, it happens occasionally.

```
@Entity
class Document {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Summary> summaries = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
class Summary {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Document document;
}
```

I have the following `@Query` in a method of a `JpaRepository`

```
@Query("select distinct d from Document d left join fetch d.summaries where d.id in (:idList)")
```

For a very specific set of `id`s in `idList` I get `LazyInitializationException` when trying to access the `summaries` collection for a specific `id` of the `Document`s returned from the query. For example the query returns 5 `Documents` (lets say with `id`s 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and only in one of them the `summaries` collection throws the exception (let it be the `Document` with `id = 2`). The other `Documents` have this collection populated with entries or empty (if the there are no summaries for this document).

**Fact 1**: the `Document` (`id:2`) that throws the exception should have this collection empty (there are no summaries for this document).

**Fact 2**: the exception is thrown only with the given, specific `idList`. If an `id` is removed from this list (but the affecting `id` (2) is still in the list) then the exception is not thrown. E.g. passing the `idList: {1, 2, 3, 4}` or `{2, 3, 4, 5}` or `{1, 2, 5}` etc won't throw the `LIE`.

Is this a nasty bug of `Hibernate`? Tested with both `5.2.17.Final` and `5.3.7.Final`